# Converting recursive formulate into pseudocode using memoization

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization, recurrence

i've been trying to turn the recurrence formula underneath into a pseudocode that uses memoization, however currently all i know is my below attempt is incorrect, is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

My recurrence formula:

```
N(C,i) =
1 if C = 0
0 if i=0 or C<0}
N(C-p_i, i-1) + N(C, i-1) otherwise
```

My current attempt:

```
MEM-N(C, i, r)
    if r[i] >= 0 then
        return r[i]
    if i = 0 and r[i] >= 0 or C < 0 and r[i] >= 0 then
        return 0
    else if C = 0 and r[i] >= 0 then
        return 1
    else
        q = -$\infty$
        q = MEM-N(C - $p_i$, i-1) + MEM-N(C,i - x, r)
        r[i] = q
        return q
```

Comment: `if r[i] <= 0 then` -- shouldn't this be `> 0`, since all return values are bound to be positive?

Comment: yes it should be >=, i made a spelling error

Comment: And perhaps `return 0` instead of `q = 0`, assuming the indentation is correct.

Comment: While that's also correct, for now all i know is there's something wrong with the recursion in the last else statement, but im not sure of what

Comment: *How* then do you know that it is wrong? Also you should pass `r` to the first recursive call.

Comment: This is an assignment for my school, where i was told that i don't have a "loop" in my recursive formula, so my q value is wrong, as well my array is only n big, and i return different values for C according to my TA, which i can't really make sense of

Comment: Now I see. There is indeed no need for the loop; you should probably put the `if r[i] >= 0 ...` clause *after* the stopping condition clauses, since the return value depends on `C` as well as `i` in this case.

Comment: So u mean like the current code as it is now?

Comment: Sorry im slightly confused, so do u mean as i edit'ed it to be now, or do you mean the last else statement should be else if r[i] >= 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from the comments:

```
MEM-N(C, i, r)
    if C = 0 then
        return 1
    else if i = 0 or C < 0 then
        return 0
    else if r[i] >= 0 then
        return r[i]                                        # move here
    else
        q = MEM-N(C - p_i, i - 1, r) + MEM-N(C, i - 1, r)  # fix
        r[i] = q
        return q
```